# Transfer of Indian rupee account funds to UAE to open business

Tags: india, investing, start-up, uae

How can I transfer from my rupee account in India a sum of Rupees 25 lacs to my UAE bank account, for investment purposes for starting my own business.

Comment: This may get better responses on https://startups.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

India has Foreign Exchange Management Act. Under the liberalized scheme, there are limits for individuals to move funds out of India for specific purposes. Any such transfer require a CA certificate, so it would be advisable to talk to a CA to understand the specifics of your case.